# Passing Array From PHP to JQuery json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an HTML form generated by php which has a dropdown of voucherproviders.

I want to select the provider and have this populate the form for editing.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).on('change','#id_voucherprovider',function(){
        var voucher_providers = <?php echo json_encode($voucher_providers); ?>;

        //The value I have got from the drop down is....
        var value = $('#id_voucherprovider option:selected').val();
        var vendortext = $('#id_voucherprovider option:selected').text();
        //so the voucher provider is
        alert(vendortext);

        $('.ftext input').val(vendortext);
        $("textarea#id_vendornotes").val(voucher_providers[value]);
    });
});
```

voucherproviders is not being passed into the JQuery despite the `echo json_encode($voucher_providers);` code working when inline with the php code.

It seems to return a null array.  Can anyone see what is wrong?

Many Thanks

Dave

Comment: Try this `var voucher_providers = '<?php echo json_encode($voucher_providers); ?>';`

Comment: If you view the source, do you see the json array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var voucher_providers = <?php echo json_encode($voucher_providers); ?>;
```

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) returns a string, unless it is parsed it will not be usable. Use JQuery [.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) and you should have better results. :)

```
var jsonString = <?php echo json_encode($voucher_providers); ?>;
var voucher_providers = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (note the quotes):
`var voucher_providers = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($voucher_providers); ?>');`

Answer (score 0):

parse your json ex: obj = JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the json format at below site:-

```
http://jsonlint.com/
```

and check if this is fine.